# How to compare and fetch remaining Folders from allotted size

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, size, directory, filesize

Hi,

I have a task to perform on batch file, where i have to check the size of all sub folders inside a particular folder, and than compare all the folders' size to allotted size(say 1000 MB or 1024000 KB) and print only the number of folder which didn't cross the mentioned threshold

I've used below code but it just give me count 1 every time i run the script, but instead i need count of the remaining folder which is still under threshold and skip the one which already cross the mark of threshold.

**Actual Code**

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
echo Folder,Size
set "folder=%~1"
if not defined folder set "folder="T:\FS_2014\FSDirs""
    for /d %%a in ("%folder%\*") do (
            set "size=0"
            for /f "tokens=3,5" %%b in ('dir /-c /a /w /s "%%~fa\*" 2^>nul ^| findstr /b /c:"  "') do if "%%~c"=="" set "size=%%~b"
                setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            set /a size1 = !size!/1024
                echo T:\FS_2014\%%~nxa,!size1!KB

            set count=0
            if !size1! LSS 1102053 set /a count=!count!+1
            echo.Remaining Folders,!count!
                endlocal
    )

endlocal
```

Comment: You are setting your count variable within a separate environment with your setlocal and endlocal.  So the variable count loses its value every time the batch file executes the endlocal.  But you are also resetting count to zero every time so it can only ever  be zero or one.

Comment: Awesome... i got the point :) thanks @Squashman